# Home depreciation real estate problem

Tags: linear-algebra

"A property sells for $96,000$ USD . If it has appreciated $4$ percent per year straight line for the past five years, what did the owner pay for the property five years ago?"

The answer listed in the answer key for this problem is $80,000$ USD, but no matter what I can't seem to get that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $P(1+0.04)^5 = 96,000$. Can you continue?